# V-Model not cleansed when adding Object to array (Vue-Js)

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to add objects (simple key-value pairs) to a list. 
However, the v-model is still bound to the previously added objects, so if I add "ObjectOne" vith "ValueOne", then try to add "ObjectTwo" with "ValueTwo", "ObjectOne" gets edited AND "ObjectTwo" gets added.

I am by no mean an expert in Javascript, so it might not be related to VueJS.

I can obviously make this work with [a method per list](https://jsfiddle.net/h3we1tzr/3/) .

The point is that my model has multiple lists of key value pair to be edited, so I tried making a generic method :

```
addToList: function(value, list){
            console.log("Adding " + value + " to list "+list);
            list.push(value);
            value={};
        },
```

This method works if used on "simple" lists (like an array of string), but not on "objects" list.

My guess is that as I try to clean "value" instead of "this.value", the reference still points to the same object, but since I don't know what "value" will be when called, I don't know how to do this.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/h3we1tzr/2/) is the fiddle with a re-creation of my issue.

My objective would be to be able to use the "addToList" function to add to any list, without having to re-write a function for each list.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The above behaviour is because you are updating the value of same object whenever you add a new todo task.You need to set your object again to add new values as below.

```
 addToList(value, todos){
    this.todos.push(value);
  this.anotherTodo={ text:'',
done:'false'}
}
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/8v01q4u7/).

Comment: Well... no. Your answer doesn't work for multiple lists since you hardcoded the "todos" list in the "addToList" method. 

If I try to use your method to add to the "anotherList" array, it won't work.

Comment: Do you want something like this?
It is working for multiple lists.Check https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/8v01q4u7/11/

Comment: That's a dirty hack. You again hard-coded the "this.anotherTodo" to be emptied, which mean that when I add an item to the second list, the "anotherTodo" model is emptied.

If "anotherList" contained object, your answer would not work : https://jsfiddle.net/b71r9Lec/

Answer (score 0):

I post this as an answer, but if someone has a better way to do it, I'm all hear.

I solved the way by adding a watch on my list. When the list changes, I clean the model object that's added to it.

In my production work, I had to add a computed property, since I can't add a watch on an object's property, then a watch on said computed property :

```
watch:{
    todos(){
        this.anotherTodo={};
    },
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onhd7epq/1/) as demo